# Invalid column name error after removing attribute

Tags: ssas

I have removed an attribute from a dimension (edited a view that feeds my dsv) because it is not wanted/needed anymore.

Now when I try to process that dimension, i get the following error;

> OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Invalid column name 'EngNation'.; 42S22.".

`EngNation` being the attribute i have deleted.

Why is it trying to process a column that doesn't exist anymore? I have refreshed the dsv and the column isn't there anymore. I've even gone through the xml-code but can't find a trace of the attribute anywhere. I just don't understand what else I have missed.

I've tried searching the web but have not been able to find an answer to my problem, any input much appreciated.

Comment: I think I had something similar. What I had to do was open Analysis Services with SSMS. Backup the database. Delete database. (it gets recreated when you process the cube.) Then see if you have the same issue.

Comment: Can you open the cube in Visual Studio, open the DSV and right click on the background and click refresh. Hoping that will remove the column from the DSV. I assume you have deleted the attribute from the dimension already.

Answer (score 0):

There is an update that fixes this:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2897265/fix-invalid-column-name-error-when-you-run-some-mdx-queries-against-ro

But if you are in a position where you cannot apply the update for whatever reason, you can see if you scenario matches ours and I will explain how I got around this error:

Three fact tables (views)
- Budget (derived from a view from an application)
- Actuals (derived from a view from an application)
- Forecast (derived from a view from an application)

Two write back tables for Forecast and Budget.

Two Dimensions
- Time
- Account Hierarchy

Three Measures:
- Actuals
- Budget
- Measure

Originally, I had three measures on each of the fact tables (views) that were Budget, Actuals, Forecast (think three views that are pretty much the exact same with three measures).  When I made it so that only the actuals view had an actuals measure, the forecast view only had a forecast measure, and the budget view only had a budget measure, everything seemed to work.

The missing column error is very misleading as the column and relationship was fine.